# Setting the FabricDataRoot for service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

According the the MS docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings), there is a Service Fabric property: FabricDataRoot that would allow me to set the data root for my installation.

I have used Azure resource manager (https://resources.azure.com) to set this value to a different value for an existing test installation, but it does not seem to have taken effect (i.e. the installation is still using the default value of d:\svcfab).

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Are you using a property named `dataPath` in your template? (so not dataPathRoot / FabricDataRoot)

Comment: It's like this: {
        "name": "Setup",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "FabricDataRoot",
            "value": "C:\\SfDevCluster\\Data"
          },
          {
            "name": "FabricLogRoot",
            "value": "C:\\SfDevCluster\\Log"
          }
        ]
      }

Comment: I've just torn down the environment and rebuilt it with this settings and it seems to be working now.